# Move mysql databases from an HDD with a dead OS

Tags: mysql

I need to move all my databases from a hard-disk with dead OS to a new one.

I've moved all files from /var/lib/mysql to new location, everything is fine, except the mysql usernames. When I access Privileges tab in phpmyadmin I receiver this error:

```
  (

SELECT DISTINCT  `User` ,  `Host` 
FROM  `mysql`.`user`
)
UNION (

SELECT DISTINCT  `User` ,  `Host` 
FROM  `mysql`.`db`
)
UNION (

SELECT DISTINCT  `User` ,  `Host` 
FROM  `mysql`.`tables_priv`
)
UNION (

SELECT DISTINCT  `User` ,  `Host` 
FROM  `mysql`.`columns_priv`
)
UNION (

SELECT DISTINCT  `User` ,  `Host` 
FROM  `mysql`.`procs_priv`
)
ORDER BY  `User` ASC ,  `Host` ASC
MySQL said: 

#1034 - Incorrect key file for table 'procs_priv'; try to repair it
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is usually caused by upgrading to a newer version of MySQL which has different privilege tables.

You can use the [mysql_fix_privilege_tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-fix-privilege-tables.html) command to fix it.